# ViewState decoding in Mojarra 2.1

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, viewstate

Mojarra 2.1

I'm trying to find the place where the `javax.faces.ViewState` parameter is decoded into the Map-like structure. In the `UIComponent` abstract class, I didn't find a method tied with RestoreView phase accepting the String as a `parameter`. The method

```
public void restoreTransientState(FacesContext context, Object state)
{
    boolean forceCreate = (state != null);
    TransientStateHelper helper = getTransientStateHelper(forceCreate);

    if (helper != null) {
        helper.restoreTransientState(context, state);
    }
 }
```

as far as I understand accept the already decoded view state and retrieve the state for that particular component saved before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the state saving method (server vs client).

In case of client side state saving, the logic to decode the `javax.faces.ViewState` request parameter is located in [`com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper#getState()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.29/com/sun/faces/renderkit/ClientSideStateHelper.java#ClientSideStateHelper.getState%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%2Cjava.lang.String%29) and subsequently [`doGetState()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.29/com/sun/faces/renderkit/ClientSideStateHelper.java#ClientSideStateHelper.doGetState%28java.lang.String%29).

In case of server side state saving, the logic to grab and decode the state object from the session using the identifier as represented by `javax.faces.ViewState` request parameter is located in [`com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper#getState()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.29/com/sun/faces/renderkit/ServerSideStateHelper.java#ServerSideStateHelper.getState%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%2Cjava.lang.String%29).

Either way, the abstract API is represented by [`ResponseStateManager#getState()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/render/ResponseStateManager.html#getState-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-java.lang.String-) which is called in [`StateManagementStrategy#restoreView()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/StateManagementStrategy.html#restoreView-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) which in turn is called during [`ViewHandler#restoreView()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html#restoreView-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-java.lang.String-). The aforelinked javadocs describe the process elaborately.